# .NET application crashes when capturing console close event only in Release build

Tags: c#, .net, events, crash, event-handling

I have a .NET application (.NET Framework 4) which monitors certain machines. I am capturing the console close event (actually CTRL+C) and ask the user if he/she is sure about it. In case the answer is yes, the application proceeds to run a method that closes open resources. 
When running it in the Debug build it works fine, the problem is running it in Release mode, when CTRL+C is pressed, the application crashes and this event is shown in Window's Event Viewer.

```
 <Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name=".NET Runtime" /> 
  <EventID Qualifiers="0">1026</EventID> 
  <Level>2</Level> 
  <Task>0</Task> 
  <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords> 
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-11-08T13:39:31.140511100Z" /> 
  <EventRecordID>25125</EventRecordID> 
  <Channel>Application</Channel> 
  <Computer>this.computer</Computer> 
  <Security /> 
  </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data>Aplicación: FooBar.exe Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319 Descripción: el proceso terminó debido a una excepción no controlada. Información de la excepción: código de la excepción c0000005, dirección de la excepción 0000000000E80B18</Data> 
  </EventData>
  </Event>
```

Below I add the code I use to invoke the method that cleans resources.

```
enum CtrlType
{
    CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
    CTRL_BREAK_EVENT = 1,
    CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT = 2,
    CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
    CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT = 6
}

private delegate bool EventHandler(CtrlType sig);

[DllImport("Kernel32")]
private static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(EventHandler handler, bool add);
private static bool Handler(CtrlType sig)
{
    if (sig == CtrlType.CTRL_C_EVENT)
    {
        DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Seguro que quieres cerrar la aplicación?", "Confirmación de cierre", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
        switch (dr)
        {
            case DialogResult.Yes:
                Environment.Exit(0); // se ejecutará la limpieza y luego se cerrará la aplicacion
                return false;
            case DialogResult.No:
                return true;
            default:
                break;
        }
    } else
    {
        DialogResult exitDialog = MessageBox.Show("La aplicación procederá a cerrarse", "Cerrando Supervisor", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
    return true;
}
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern int DeleteMenu(IntPtr hMenu, int nPosition, int wFlags);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr GetSystemMenu(IntPtr hWnd, bool bRevert);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);
#endregion

#region Methods
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SetConsoleCtrlHandler(Handler, true);
    Console.Title = GlobalConfig.Title;
    Console.Clear();
    DeleteMenu(GetSystemMenu(GetConsoleWindow(), false), 0xF060, 0x00000000);
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), 5);

    //AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += new System.EventHandler(CleanBeforeExit);

    init();
}

static void CleanBeforeExit(object sender, EventArgs e) { ... }
```

If I use the ProcessExit way it won't crash, but it won't execute my `CleanBeforeExit` method either.

Does anybody know how to solve this? I don't think the client (a really important one) would accept an application in Build config (or isn't it really important?).

Comment: I have try some build config, and your example work fine. Juste I have removed the line `init();`. What is the method init?

Comment: @Orwel Have you tried only Debug build? As I said in the post, the issue is in the Release build only. In the former it works fine.

Comment: I have try in debug, realease, x86, x64, with/without optimization... It's work fine. But I have replaced `init();` by `Thread.Sleep(10000);` to simulate a work.

Comment: @Orwel oh sorry I understood that you had tried debug build (my bad). Anyways, init() configures log4net and then there is more code in Main method, which runs the application. Did you try using .NET 4.0 ?

Comment: I have test only with .NET 4.0. Can you post a minimal example to reproduce the crash? Maybe the problem concern machine/OS (I use Windows 10 Pro). Have you try on other computer?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving it by using an EventHandler variable

`static EventHandler _handler;`

and

```
_handler += new EventHandler(Handler);
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(_handler, true);
```

instead of

```
SetConsoleCtrlHandler(Handler, true);
```